# Stored Procedure return value in petapoco always returns -1 (not output parameter)

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, petapoco

I'm trying something like:

```
            using (var db = new Database(ConnectionString, DataProvider))
            {
                var spResult =
                    db.Execute("exec [cmtUpdateOrganization] @Id,@FullName",
                               new
                                   {
                                       organizatonData.Id,
                                       organizatonData.FullName
                                   }
                        );
                if (spResult == 0 || spResult == 1)
                    return true;
                return false;
            }
```

But it appears the spResult is always -1.

Although in the stored procedure, it definately returns 0. I validated with the same parameters on sql server itself.

Output parameters work fine, but that is not what i prefer to do as it involves changing a lot of stored procedures.

Comment: I missed the "petapoco" part in your question. So I deleted my answer to make sure nobody gets the wrong idea. Hope someone sees your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Execute method in PetaPoco just calls the ExecuteNonQuery() method form the SqlCommand object.

Here is there reason why you are returning -1, which comes directly from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx).

> **Quoted from MSDN**
>
> You can use the ExecuteNonQuery to perform catalog operations (for
> example, querying the structure of a database or creating database
> objects such as tables), or to change the data in a database without
> using a DataSet by executing UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE statements.
>
> Although the ExecuteNonQuery returns no rows, any output parameters or
> return values mapped to parameters are populated with data.
>
> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
> number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
> table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
> of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
> of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. **For all other types of
> statements, the return value is -1**. If a rollback occurs, the return
> value is also -1.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your proc look likes. However, if it's does an insert (correctly), it should return 1. Else, it will return -1;

Here's my code on testing this:

**SQL PROC and TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE test(id INT, name VARCHAR(50), InsertDate DATETIME)

CREATE proc cmtUpdateOrganization (@id int, @FullName varchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(Select id from Test where Id = @id)
    BEGIN
        INSERT test(id,Name, InsertDate)values(@id, @FullName, GETDATE());
    END
END
GO
```

Here's my code. First time, you should get 1. second time for the same data, -1.

**CODE**

```
    try {
        string sql = "exec cmtUpdateOrganization @Id, @FullName";
        using (var db = new DB()) {
            db.EnableAutoSelect = false;
            var result = db.Execute(sql, new { Id = 1, FullName = "Name" });
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Your result is {0}", result));
        }

    } catch ( Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
```